# How to define PID in diff_drive_controller

Tags: ros, diff-drive-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to understand how **diff_drive_controller** works by following the documentation: http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller

1 - I don't understand why the PID parameters are not set ?

2 - If these parameters are not useful, then I would like to understand how the system manages to regulate itself ?

---

Thank you for your answer, I understand.

So DiffDriveController allows to calculate the speed of each wheel then send this speed to the motor (VelocityJointInterface) the motor must be controlled by the speed.

In the case where a DC motor driven with an arduino and H bridge is used, the speed control loop is implemented at the level of the arduino, which makes configuration difficult.

For my part I wrote an effort controller (effort_controllers/JointVelocityController) for each wheel. This controller allows to control each wheel individually in speed.

```
drive_train:
  wheels_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 50

  left_wheel_joint_velocity_controller:
    type: effort_controllers/JointVelocityController
    joint: left_wheel_joint
    pid: {p: 6.0, i: 21.0, d: 0.0, i_clamp_min: -255.0, i_clamp_max: 255, antiwindup: True}


  right_wheel_joint_velocity_controller:
    type: effort_controllers/JointVelocityController
    joint: right_wheel_joint
    pid: {p: 6.0, i: 21.0, d: 0.0, i_clamp_min: -255.0, i_clamp_max: 255, antiwindup: True}
```

Is it possible to use the controller I just wrote in DiffDriveController. Indeed the real time constraint will not be respected, but it is more logical from an architectural point of view. If possible can you show me how to do it..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417072/how-to-define-pid--in-diff_drive_controller/) by [hdd--robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/155797/hdd--robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2023-06-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2023-07-01**:
It's not clear what question you are asking.

To support experimentation, `move_base` & `ros_control` are highly modular, and support control-feedback mechanisms in multiple places. You are unlikely to understand the big picture just by looking at the `diff_drive_controller` plugin to ros_control. Part of the story is explained by http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control (but this page is not a tutorial.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [DiffDriveController](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/dce87855e1adf3a66271db8243d58561da9f2cdb/diff_drive_controller/include/diff_drive_controller/diff_drive_controller.h) forwards incoming velocity commands to the `VelocityJointInterface`s [it has been configured to control](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/dce87855e1adf3a66271db8243d58561da9f2cdb/diff_drive_controller/src/diff_drive_controller.cpp#L346-L354), after [converting the `Twist` into velocities for the individual joints](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/dce87855e1adf3a66271db8243d58561da9f2cdb/diff_drive_controller/src/diff_drive_controller.cpp#L461-L500).

> I don't understand why the PID parameters are not set ?

You don't specify *which* PIDs you refer to, but since this is an open-loop (most likely always linear) conversion, there are no gains to configure.

> If these parameters are not useful, then I would like to understand how the system manages to regulate itself ?

To answer your question very directly: there is nothing to regulate, at least not at the `DiffDriveController` level, with an open-loop hw interface, and the default configurations.

The `VelocityJointInterface` handles which communicate with the underlying system/controller/embedded-hw/something else have the responsibility to ensure the wheels attain the velocities commanded by the `DiffDriveController`.

In other words: the `DiffDriveController` does not consider it its responsibility to close the loop at the velocity level. That responsibility is delegated to whatever entity is actually controlling motor/wheel velocity, and which accepts the setpoints the `DiffDriveController` calculates (based on the incoming `Twist`).

`ros_control` nomenclature for this would be something akin to the [forward_command](http://wiki.ros.org/forward_command_controller) controllers, which also don't close the loop, but open-loop forward whatever command they receive to the underlying hw.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3